# Update Filter Criteria in SharePoint list using workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, office-365

I have a list that has about 25 views that I manually have to update on a monthly basis.  I have to go into each view and change the "Fiscal Period" to the current year and month (201709)  I want to know if it is possible to do this via a SPD workflow or other method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1**

Create filtered list views and have their Urls as hyperlinks in a content editor web part. Place that web part on the top of the page. Example code for content editor web part is

```
<h2>2017</h2>
<a href="/site/Lists/Test/AllItems.aspx?FilterField1=Year&FilterValue1=2017&FilterField2=Month&FilterValue2=Jan">Jan</a> | 
<a href="/site/Lists/Test/AllItems.aspx?FilterField1=Year&FilterValue1=2017&FilterField2=Month&FilterValue2=Feb">Feb</a> | 
<a href="/site/Lists/Test/AllItems.aspx?FilterField1=Year&FilterValue1=2017&FilterField2=Month&FilterValue2=Jan">Mar</a>​​
```

and that gives the output with clickable Jan, Feb and so on.

[image]

**Solution 2**

Create a form with year and month dropdowns and a submit submit to redirect to itself with querystring params. Example `FilterField1=Year&FilterValue1=2017&FilterField2=Month&FilterValue2=Jan`. Place that form html in a content editor web part at the top of the page.

**Solution 3**

Create a console application to update the list views and schedule it. A timer service can also be created.

Comment: Thanks for these suggestions but wouldn't I need to do this on each of the views since that is its "own" page of sorts?  I am a bit confused.

Comment: @Dorinda, if you were referring to solution 1, you need to add content editor web part on only one page. This page could be `AllItems.aspx` which is a view of the list. So when you click on lets say Feb, the page would reload and display all the items with month Jan.